# How to restore dynamodb to its initial state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, backup, aws-cloudformation, restore

I am quite new to AWS and i am currently working with cloudformation, lambdas, dynamodb etc.

I need to restore a dynamo table which i was successful in doing, but as per AWS documentation, the following should be set manually:

- Auto scaling policies
- IAM policies
- Cloudwatch metrics and alarms
- Tags
- Stream settings
- Time to Live (TTL) settings

I could not find any documentation about how to achieve this, so i am trying my own idea which is to put the resources that needs to be set manually in a separate stack or nested stack, then deleting the nested stack **resource** and deploying the template again.

I was able to do it for autoscaling since it is a completely different resource and can be done in a separate stack.

My question is that: is it possible to split the resource in separate template?
e.g. Main dynamodb table definition in main cloudformation stack, other definition such as tags and streams in the nested stack?

cloudformation-template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: this is a test app

Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String
    Default: test
Resources:
  # dynamodb table
  UserTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: User
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
      Tags:
        - Key: Environment
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}
        - Key: table
          Value: user
  AutoscalingStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      Parameters:
        EnvironmentName: !Ref EnvironmentName
        UserTable: !Ref UserTable
      TemplateURL: autoscaling-template.yaml
      TimeoutInMinutes: 5
```

autoscaling-template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: test autoscaling

Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Type: String
    Default: playground
  UserTable:
    Type: String
Resources:
  UpdateUserTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: !Ref UserTable
      Tags:
        - Key: Environment
          Value: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}
        - Key: table
          Value: user
  UserTableWriteCapacityScalable:
    Type: "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget"
    Properties:
      MaxCapacity: 1000
      MinCapacity: 5
      ResourceId: !Join
        - /
        - - table
          - !Ref UserTable
      RoleARN: !ImportValue "autoscaling--ScalingRole"
      ScalableDimension: dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits
      ServiceNamespace: dynamodb
  UserTableReadCapacityScalable:
    Type: "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget"
    Properties:
      MaxCapacity: 1000
      MinCapacity: 5
      ResourceId: !Join
        - /
        - - table
          - !Ref UserTable
      RoleARN: !ImportValue "autoscaling--ScalingRole"
      ScalableDimension: dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits
      ServiceNamespace: dynamodb
  UserTableWriteScalingPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy"
    Properties:
      PolicyName: WriteAutoScalingPolicy
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      ScalingTargetId: !Ref UserTableWriteCapacityScalable
      TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
        TargetValue: 50.0
        ScaleInCooldown: 30
        ScaleOutCooldown: 30
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization
  UserTableReadScalingPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalingPolicy"
    Properties:
      PolicyName: ReadAutoScalingPolicy
      PolicyType: TargetTrackingScaling
      ScalingTargetId: !Ref UserTableReadCapacityScalable
      TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration:
        TargetValue: 50.0
        ScaleInCooldown: 20
        ScaleOutCooldown: 20
        PredefinedMetricSpecification:
          PredefinedMetricType: DynamoDBReadCapacityUtilization
```

The `UpdateUserTable` does not work since it is not valid. But the rest works fine when i remove and add the nested stack after restoring.